# Bigram in python

Tags: python, python-3.3

I wanted to divide a sentence into bi-grams. For example:

```
"My name is really nice. This is so awesome."
```

-->

```
["My name","name is", "is really", "really nice.", "This is", "is so", "so awesome."]
```

Any help?

Comment: This is in no way related to the "Rolling or Sliding Window iterator in Python", inspectorG4dget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this through positive lookahead,

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "My name is really nice. This is so awesome."
>>> m = re.findall(r'(?=(\b\w+\b \S+))', s)
>>> m
['My name', 'name is', 'is really', 'really nice.', 'This is', 'is so', 'so awesome.']
```

**Pattern Explanation:**

- `(?=...)` Lookaheads are  zero-length assertions just like the start and end of line, and start and end of word. It won't consume characters in the string, but only assert whether a match is possible or not.
- `()` Capturing group which was used to capture  characters which matches the pattern present inside the ().
- `\b` Word boundary. It matches between a word character and a  non-word character.
- `\w+` Matches one or more word characters.
- `\S+` Matches the space and the following non-space characters.
- `findall` function usually prints the characters inside the captured groups. If there is no capturing groups then it would print the matches. In our case it would prints the characters which was present inside the group index 1. To match overlapping characters, you need to put the pattern inside a lookahead.

Comment: It would be really nice if you could explain your answer sir

Answer (score 1):

```
def ngrams(words, n):
    return [words[i:i+n] for i in range(len(words)-n+1)]
```

Output:

```
In [67]: ngrams("My name is really nice".split(),2)
Out[67]: [['My', 'name'], ['name', 'is'], ['is', 'really'], ['really', 'nice']]
```

Answer (score 0):

First you can use `split('.')` for split sentences in your string again `split` every sentence then with [zip()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) you can concatenate them!

```
>>> [' '.join(i) for s2 in s.split('.') for i in zip(s2.split(),s2.split()[1:])]
['My name', 'name is', 'is really', 'really nice', 'This is', 'is so', 'so awesome']
>>>
```

Comment: yes i edit and split the string with '.' first !